# Bootstrap columns are overlapping after positioning

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap 4 grid system with simple two columns. I want my left column to be fixed and right column to be scroll able. Problem is when i set the position of left col. fixed. it takes it out of the flow of page and right column overlaps it. I have used offset-md which solves the problem as far as the screen size is of md or greater but when i resize the browser, again the right overlaps in smaller screen. now i cant figure out how to solve this for smaller screen.

My HTML:

```
  <div class="row">

     <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 h-100"  id="left">

         <div id="introduction" >
          <h1>Hi, I'm Nawal Shaukat! </h1>   
          <p>Full Stack Web Developer</p>
         </div>

     </div>

     <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-sm-12" id="right">     

     <h2>Get to know me!</h2>                
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
<hr>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

my css:

 html,body{
         height: 100%;
         margin:0;
     }

     #left{
         position:fixed;
         height:100%;
         background-image:url("profile-pic.png");
         background-repeat:no-repeat;
         background-size:cover;  
     }
```

Comment: please add css code you are made for this structure.

Comment: i have added the css. there is nothing much in css. its just when i apply position fixed to left column everything overlaps

Comment: .col-sm-offset-6  try adding this class

Comment: yes i have tried this too. didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Like this?
I added viewport height to both classes and make `#right` to scrollable.

```css
#left, #right {
    height:100vh;
}

#right {
    overflow-y: scroll; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row m-0">

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"  id="left">

        <div id="introduction" >
            <h1>Hi, I'm Nawal Shaukat! </h1>   
            <p>Full Stack Web Developer</p>
        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12" id="right">     
        <h2>Get to know me!</h2>                
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.qua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
        <hr>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to just add following CSS code,

```
#right {
  margin-left: 52%;
}
```

When you take position:fixed; then next element can occupy its position so you need to add the margin to next element according to previous element which you gives fixed position. 
Following code will help you,

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

#left {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url("profile-pic.png");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

#right {
  margin-left: 54%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">

  <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12 h-100" id="left">

    <div id="introduction">
      <h1>Hi, I'm Nawal Shaukat! </h1>
      <p>Full Stack Web Developer</p>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-6 col-sm-12" id="right">

    <h2>Get to know me!</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur.Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <hr>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want the left column fixed and right column scrollable right? Can you check my code snippet? Is this anything wrong in output? Then explain to me then I will solve. :)